# How to convert "&lt;/body&gt;" to "</body>" in java

Tags: java, html

Some how in the middle of a process in java html source codes are effected by this unwanted conversion. For example now I have:

```
&lt;body topmargin=&quot;0&quot; leftmargin=&quot;0&quot; bgcolor=&quot;#000000&quot;&gt; &lt;center&gt;&lt;p&gt;
```

I want to convert this string back to the original one.

Comment: Yes it is the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

The trivial way would be to use String replace method.
The safer way would be to use commons-lang API to accomplish this job.
Java doc here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(respString)